# Trouble with using Text Mesh in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, mesh

So the problem is that I want create such an idea. There are a table and a sheet of paper (just a Plane). I want to place some text on this sheet of paper. I read about Text Mesh and I thought that I would use it but I had a problem about it. I need to limit my text on this sheet of paper but I haven't found any borders I can place there. How can I set borders to Text Mesh? Or are there any decision I can use to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `TextMesh` does not have borders

Instead, you are probably interested in a World Space Canvas and using UI text instead. Unity has a [great tutorial in the manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html) for setting up a world space canvas, which pretty much amounts to "set the Canvas to world space, decide on a resolution, decide on a in-game size, and position it."

For text, you actually have two options: UI Text and Text Mesh Pro. TMP used to be an asset on the asset store, but Unity has integrated it into a semi-standard package now (just create a TMP object and you'll be prompted to do the importing). TMP has several additional features and options that standard UI Text does not have, including in-line sprites, margins, text alignment, better rich-text, and so on. It might be overkill, but it is available.